# How can I fix this error? (Corona SDK)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

So I am getting this error from this bock of code, and I want to know what I could do to make this work. The error says "ERROR: table expected. If this is a function call, you might have used '.' instead of ':'" I'm still learning lua so this is very confusing to me, and if you could provide an answer I would much appreciate it.

```
function scene:create( event )
--Declared variables
local sceneGroup = self.view
local background = display.newImage( "game_background.jpg", display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    background.anchorX = 0
    background.anchorY = 0
    background.x, background.y = 0, 0
--Rotation Function for Object "Basket"
local function rotateBasket(event)
    --Declared Variables inside rotation function
    local t = event.target
    local phase = event.phase
    local basket = display.newImageRect("basket.jpg" , 90, 60)
    basket.x = display.contentCenterX
    basket.y = display.contentCenterY
    --Rotation
    if (phase == "began") then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( t )
        t.isFocus = true
        t.x1 = event.x
        t.y1 = event.y
    elseif t.isFocus then
        if (phase == "moved") then
            t.x2 = event.x
            t.y2 = event.y
            angle1 = 180/math.pi * math.atan2(t.y1 - t.y , t.x1 - t.x)
            angle2 = 180/math.pi * math.atan2(t.y2 - t.y , t.x2 - t.x)
            rotationAmt = angle1 - angle2
            t.rotation = t.rotation - rotationAmt
            t.x1 = t.x2
            t.y1 = t.y2
        elseif (phase == "ended") then
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
            t.isFocus = false
        end
    end
    --Event Listener
    basket:addEventListener("touch", rotateBasket)
    return true
end
--sceneGroup insertions
sceneGroup:insert( background )
sceneGroup:insert( basket )
end
```

Comment: Do you have any indication about *where* in that code the error is coming from? A line? A phase? Anything?

Comment: yes it said the error was coming from somewhere close to the scene group insertions.

Comment: Your `basket` variable is local to the `rotateBasket` function. It doesn't exist in the `scene:create` function where you are trying to use it.

Comment: so do I have to declare it twice? Both in the scene:create function AND rotateBasket function?

Comment: If you want to operate on the same object, no. You want to do it once and use the same object in both functions. But I'm not sure what you are doing so I can't say specifically what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the way you declare the function that's a bit wrong. You're declaring the display object `basket` inside your `rotateBasket`, which will make `basket` inaccessible outside of that function. I'm assuming that you're declaring a background and a basket image you want to rotate, so, assuming your `rotateBasket` function is correct, you may try something like this:

```
--Rotation Function for Object "Basket"
local function rotateBasket(event)
    --Declared Variables inside rotation function
    local t = event.target
    local phase = event.phase

    --Rotation
    if (phase == "began") then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( t )
        t.isFocus = true
        t.x1 = event.x
        t.y1 = event.y
    elseif t.isFocus then
        if (phase == "moved") then
            t.x2 = event.x
            t.y2 = event.y
            angle1 = 180/math.pi * math.atan2(t.y1 - t.y , t.x1 - t.x)
            angle2 = 180/math.pi * math.atan2(t.y2 - t.y , t.x2 - t.x)
            rotationAmt = angle1 - angle2
            t.rotation = t.rotation - rotationAmt
            t.x1 = t.x2
            t.y1 = t.y2
        elseif (phase == "ended") then
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
            t.isFocus = false
        end
    end
    return true
end

function scene:create( event )
    --Declared variables
    local sceneGroup = self.view

    --Create background
    local background = display.newImage( "game_background.jpg", display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    background.anchorX = 0
    background.anchorY = 0
    background.x, background.y = 0, 0

    --Create basket 
    local basket = display.newImageRect("basket.jpg" , 90, 60)
    basket.x = display.contentCenterX
    basket.y = display.contentCenterY

    --Add event listener to basket (may also be done in scene:show function)
    basket:addEventListener("touch", rotateBasket)  

    --sceneGroup insertions
    sceneGroup:insert( background )
    sceneGroup:insert( basket )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you declaring the local basket inside the function and trying to insert in to the scenegroup outside the function, since it is local cannot be accessed outside the function.

```
--Rotation Function for Object "Basket"
 local function rotateBasket(event)
  --Declared Variables inside rotation function
  local t = event.target
  local phase = event.phase
  local basket = display.newImageRect("basket.jpg" , 90, 60)
  basket.x = display.contentCenterX
  basket.y = display.contentCenterY
--Rotation
if (phase == "began") then
    display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( t )
    t.isFocus = true
    t.x1 = event.x
    t.y1 = event.y
elseif t.isFocus then
    if (phase == "moved") then
        t.x2 = event.x
        t.y2 = event.y
        angle1 = 180/math.pi * math.atan2(t.y1 - t.y , t.x1 - t.x)
        angle2 = 180/math.pi * math.atan2(t.y2 - t.y , t.x2 - t.x)
        rotationAmt = angle1 - angle2
        t.rotation = t.rotation - rotationAmt
        t.x1 = t.x2
        t.y1 = t.y2
    elseif (phase == "ended") then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
        t.isFocus = false
    end
end
 sceneGroup:insert( basket )
 --Event Listener
 basket:addEventListener("touch", rotateBasket)
 return true
end
 --sceneGroup insertions
 sceneGroup:insert( background )
```